# How can I get a variable from main.py module to use in another parameters module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been tried to improve my code, using a sensitivity analysis of my model. The model is agent based model to simulate economics in a country.

I need to variate 8 parameters, each one at least over 10 different values. So, I have been doing this "by hand" is a little bit complicate (because I do some mistakes) and take a lot of time.

My model is constructed by a sequence, I run the "my_control.py" that control the number of repetitions and (I hope will) control the parameters selection to test. This "my_control.py" call the "my_main.py" where is descripted the "orders", and, the "main.py" call the "generator.py" where create my population. And so on...

So, I develop the process in "R style" (beacuse I have a little bit more experience in R), using the "sys.argvs" from the three loops of "my_control.py". The first loop is to controll the number of regions, the second one is to select the parameter among my 8 parameters, and the third one will used to select the value inside a sequence created with the values selected as the second loop.

Theoretically it would work, but it's doesn't work.

So,  thank's in advance.

```
# my_control.py module

__author__ = 'Isaque'
import os

for reg in range(3):
    for prm_test in range(10):
        for prm_to_run in range(10):
            cmd = "python mainmodel.py "+ str(reg) +" "+ str(prm_test) +" "+ str(prm_to_run)
            print cmd
            os.system(cmd)

# my_parameters.py module 

from __future__ import division
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# System constrain: number of households should be larger than number of families
# System constrain: number of members in a family is determined by the average ratio of inputs #agents #families

#CREATING THE PARAMETERS IN DEFAULT VALUES
# RUN PARAMETERS 
TOTAL_DAYS = 5040
TOTAL_AGENTS = 1000
TOTAL_FAMILIES = 400
TOTAL_HOUSEHOLDS = 450
TOTAL_FIRMS = 110
ALPHA = .2
BETA = .9
QUANTITY_TO_CHANGE_PRICES = 10
PERCENTAGE_CHANGE_PRICES = 0.05
LABOUR_MARKET = 0.3
SIZE_MARKET = 10
CONSUMPTION_SATISFACTION = .1
PERCENTAGE_CHECK_NEW_LOCATION = 0.1
TAX_CONSUMPTION = 0.01

# AUTOMATED SELECTION OF PARAMETERS 
# CREATING A REGIONS NUMBER OBJECT

def prm():
    regions = pd.DataFrame({"NUMBER_REGIONS" : [1,  4, 7]})
    # CREATING A OBJECT WITH ALL PARAMETERS VARIATION POSSIBLE
    prm_parameters = pd.DataFrame({"Parameters":('SIZE_MARKET','ALPHA','BETA','QUANTITY_TO_CHANGE_PRICES', 'PERCENTAGE_CHANGE_PRICES','LABOUR_MARKET','CONSUMPTION_SATISFACTION','PERCENTAGE_CHECK_NEW_LOCATION','TAX_CONSUMPTION')})
    # Parameters values
    #"prm_start" is the lowest value to test that parameter in the model
    #"prm_end" is the highest value to test that parameter in the model
    #"prm_num_classes" is the number of classes for the intervall of each o test that parameter in the model
    #                                            Market  Alpha  Beta    Qt.  %Price   Labour  Sats.   Loc.   Tax
    prm_start  =  pd.DataFrame({"Start"        : (1,     0.1,   0.1,   10,    0.01,   0.1,   0.01,   0.01,  0.1)})
    prm_end  =  pd.DataFrame({"End"            : (50,      1,     1,   1000,   1,       1,     1,      1,    1)})
    prm_num_classes = pd.DataFrame({"N_classes": (10,     10,    10,    10,    10,     10,     10,    10,    10)})
    parameters_to_test = pd.concat([prm_parameters, prm_start,prm_end,prm_num_classes], axis=1)

    # CALLING THE ARGV FROM LOOPS TO SELECT THE VALUES OF PARAMETERS IN MY OBJECT "parameters_to_test"
    # "reg_index" will be used to test the different number of regions in the model
    reg_index = sys.argv[1]
    # "prm_test" and "prm_to_run" will be used to select the parameters values inside of "parameters_to_test" object
    prm_test = sys.argv[2]
    prm_to_run = sys.argv[3]

    #renaming the variable for "NUMBER_REGIONS" selected to test
    globals()["NUMBER_REGIONS"] = int(regions.iloc[reg_index])
    # Selecting the row (each row represent one parameter)
    prm_run = parameters_to_test.iloc[prm_test]
    # Creating a variable length to generate the sequence of parameters
    interval_out = prm_run['End']/prm_run['N_classes']
    # Creating the sequence with all possible values to test
    seq_prm_run = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(prm_run['Start'],(prm_run['End']+interval_out),interval_out))
    # Selecting the name of variable from the selected row that create the sequence
    name_prm = str(prm_run['Parameters'])
    #Selecting the value inside the sequence and renaming the variable as the name
    globals()[name_prm] = (seq_prm_run.iloc[prm_to_run])[0]
    print name_prm
    print (seq_prm_run.iloc[prm_to_run])[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
            prm()
```

Comment: "The problem is, I cannot make the selection of parameters in this way." To be clear, does the program halt with a bug? Or not terminate? Or is it that the results are bad? It's a very different question depending on what the exact problem is.

Comment: Please consider posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get better/faster answers.

Comment: So, I work some time in the problem, and make some progress. 
Now, the problem is to use the argvs to select the what parameter, form the sequence and select the value of the sequence.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the error you're having is, but I think you'll find things vastly simpler if you stop calling your scripts from one another with `os.system` and instead import the relevant modules and call functions in them. That way you can pass parameters to the functions without messing around with `sys.argv` and access the variables in a module with a simple attribute lookup. `import module_x; print(module_x.foo)`